# $('.block').height($(this).width()); causing block height extend

Tags: jquery, height, width

I am trying to set a block's height equal to its width with this `$('.block').height($(this).width());` However it's not working properly for some reason. Please see an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Uy3YB/. What do I need to correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/P6xDT/)

```
$('.block').height(function () {
    return $(this).width();
});
```

[.height( function(index, height) )](https://api.jquery.com/height/#height-functionindex--height)

> A function returning the height to set. Receives the index position of the element in the set and the old height as arguments. Within the function, this refers to the current element in the set

---

Problem with your code

`this` below is the `window` object not `$('.block')`

```
$('.block').height($(this).width());
```

Comment: Thanks I see. Is it possible to combine it with window.onresize=function(){ } ?

Comment: @YevgenySimzikov What do you think about it? Don't think too much, just try!

Comment: @YevgenySimzikov not clear what you want but see --> http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/P6xDT/1/ and resize the Result partition.